# OS X 10.8 Server + PHP 5.3.15 + MSSQL: подключение к базе в локальной сети

Tags: mac, php, sql-server

Добрый день, уже второй день пытаюсь подключится к базе `MS SQL` которая находится в локальной сети с Веб сервера который работает под управлением OS X. 
Пробовал стандартными средствами `odbc_connect();` но коннекта нету, даже ошибку не возвращает.  
Также успешно получилось скачать `FreeTDS` скомпилировал `mssql.so, php` его взял, но `mssql_connect();` также не подключается к базе. доступ к базе по локальной сети есть.

Вот примеры, которые не работают:

```
<?php
    odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=192.168.1.94\SQLEXPRESS;Database=database;", "sa", "1234") or die ('error');
?>
<?php
    $db_host = "Notebook_HP\SQLEXPRESS"; 
    $db_user = "sa"; 
    $db_pass = "1234"; 
    $dbhandle = mssql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $db_host. Error: " . mssql_get_last_message());
?>
```

Comment: попробуй добавить cursor_type у odbc_connect.

и что в итоге получаешь?, error или Couldn't connect to SQL Server ?

Comment: Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $db_host. Error:

Comment: еще попробовал вот так, 
try{
$dbc = new PDO( 'odbc:DRIVER={MSSQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=WINNER;UID=sa;PWD=1234;' );
echo 'OK';
}
catch( PDOException $e ){
echo 'Error: ',$e->getMessage();
}
пишет Error: could not find driver